# Как выполнить функцию после изменения значений переменной?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция `flip`, которая выводит поочередно значения, которые хранятся в переменной `h`. Как сделать так, чтобы `h` одновременно менялась во всех уже запущенных функциях `flip`?

```
var cur = 1
if (cur > 0) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval = 500;
    var refresh = function() {
        count++;
        h--;
        flip('hoursUp' + count, 'hoursDown' + count, h,
                'Single/Up/' + 2 + '/', 'Single/Down/' + 1 + '/');
        setTimeout(function() {
            refresh();
        }, interval);
    };
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: Что значит "уже запущенных"? Функцию вызвали, она отработала, функция кончилась. Как можно что-то менять в уже отработавшем коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно использовать глобальную переменную `h`, но это не очень хорошее решение, можно изучить [область видимости](http://habrahabr.ru/post/239863/)

```
var cur = 1,
    h = 0;
if (cur > 0) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval = 500;
    var refresh = function() {
        count++;
        h--;
        flip('hoursUp' + count, 'hoursDown' + count, h,
                'Single/Up/' + 2 + '/', 'Single/Down/' + 1 + '/');
        setTimeout(function() {
            refresh();
        }, interval);
    };
    refresh();
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, можно передать начальное значение `h` в замыкание и уже в нем определять `refresh` и специальную переменную, используемую вместо глобальной `h`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так попробовать

```
function Foobar() {
 this.h = 0
 this.doStuff = function(){
 //ваш код ссылаемся на h через this.h
 }
}
```

Создаем экземпляр `var foobar = new Foobar()` и вызываем `foobar.doStuff()`.

Comment: нажал не ту кнопку, удалите

Comment: Вы можете сами это сделать. Но ещё Вы можете второй свой ответ поместить в этот. Под ответом есть небольшие серые подписи, одна из них - "править"

Comment: все, разобрался, спасибо :)